# Запятые при перечислении

Tags: запятые, перечисление

> Автор — И. В. Зайцев, историк-востоковед, доктор исторических наук,
> заместитель генерального директора Государственного музея Востока.

По-моему, последняя запятая лишняя, или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая ставится:

*Автор — И. В. Зайцев, **историк-востоковед, доктор исторических наук, заместитель генерального директора Государственного музея Востока.***

Если приложение стоит **после определяемого слова**, то оно в любом случае считается **однородным.**  То есть мы имеем **одно формальное решение** для любого вида приложений (однородных или неоднородных).

Розенталь § 11. Однородные и неоднородные приложения, п. 2. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=99#pp99

**Примечание.** Приложения неоднородные, когда они стоят перед определяемым существительным, **становятся однородными** в положении после определяемого слова; ср.. *новатор производства токарь Ильин — Ильин, новатор производства, токарь.*